# How to change/inject some html for an url in the browser cache

Tags: html, url, browser, browser-cache, inject

Ok so for example I want for the website www.google.com to inject or to modify the webpage and for example to add a div with some info. How can I do this with the browser. I want to create a program, a user will download it and it will have the homepage for Google changed. I searched and I found out that this is done with the browser cache for a specific url? Thanks for help and sorry for my english!